# Nested radicals; $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}{}\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}} - \sqrt{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, nested-radicals

**I have the following problem:**
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}}-\sqrt{x}=?
$$

The answer in the answer section is $\frac{1}{2}$.

**What I've tried:**

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}\frac{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}}\frac{(x-\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}})}{(x-\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}})}
$$

I tried a couple of other simplifying approaches but unfortunately nothing got me near a limit of $\frac{1}{2}$, which makes me think that it's some other approach I'm unaware of.

Edit: Sorry for the error in the problem. It's how it was in the book and not my fault in rewriting it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There must be something wrong with the question, since this is obviously unbounded. What is the real sequence? Is it $\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{\dotso}}}}}}$

Comment: The function is greater than $\sqrt{x}$, so the limit is $\infty$. Check the source to make sure you've stated the problem correctly.

Comment: How is there a limit?  It looks like the function increases without bound.  Did we forget a term?

Comment: How is there a limit?  It looks like the function increases without bound.  Did we forget a term?

Comment: $$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt x}}\ge\sqrt x\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\infty$$ . Check your expression

Comment: Or is it just $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt x}}-\sqrt x=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x+\sqrt x}}{\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt x}}+\sqrt x}=\frac12?$$

Comment: @Cornman I guess there was really an error. It's an old edition of the problem book and there are many errors I suppose. I should start using a newer one with corrected errors. Thanks for the edit to whoever figured out what the actual statement was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $x \to \infty$,
$$
\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}} = \sqrt{x}\;\big({1+x^{-1/2}}\big)^{1/2}
= x^{1/2}\big(1+O(x^{-1/2})\big)
= x^{1/2}+ O(1)
$$
and then
$$
\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}} = \sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+\frac{x^{1/2} + O(1)}{x}}
= x^{1/2}\left(1+x^{-1/2}+O(x^{-1})\right)^{1/2}
\\
x^{1/2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\;x^{-1/2}+O(x^{-1})\right)
= x^{1/2}+\frac{1}{2} + O(x^{-1/2})
$$
so that
$$
\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}} - \sqrt{x} = \frac{1}{2} + O(x^{-1/2})
$$
and we get limit $\frac{1}{2}$.

> We used, twice, $\sqrt{1+y} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}y + O(y^2)$ as $y \to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

With the substitution $x=1/t^2$, the limit is the same as
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}
\left(
  \sqrt{\frac{1}{t^2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{t^2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{t^2}}}}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{t^2}}
\right)=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{1+t\sqrt{1+t}}-1}{t}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\frac{1}{2}t\sqrt{1+t}+o(t\sqrt{1+t}\,)}{t}
$$